# Column Set to 0 Instead of Date Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to set a column to the current date (in the form dd/mm/yyyy) in a stored procedure, however the column simply sets to 0. The code is as below:

```
USE [DBDataOne]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

declare @dateone varchar(max)
declare @dodate varchar(max)

select @dateone=convert(varchar,GETDATE(),103 )

select @dodate='Update [dbo].[tabfget] set DATEIN='+@dateone

exec (@dodate)
```

Comment: How is your `tabfget` table designed?

Comment: Without quotes it's probably evaluating as integer division. I can't remember what format 103 looks like though... Ok yeah, month divided by day divided by year is definitely going to be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `datein` is stored properly (as a date/time), then you don't need to worry about conversion.

Also, you don't need dynamic SQL for this.  Just:

```
Update [dbo].[tabfget]
    set DATEIN = cast(getdate() as date);
```

If -- horror of horrors -- you are storing dates as *strings* instead of the proper format, then you should fix the database.  If that is not possible, you can do:

```
Update [dbo].[tabfget]
    set DATEIN = convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103);
```

However, if dates *have* to be stored as strings, then you should *always* use an ISO-standard format, such as YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Is thee any way to include slashes / instead of dashes -  ?

Comment: @KieraSmith . . . There might be a format for that.  Or, just use `replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you directly do like

```
Update [dbo].[tabfget] set DATEIN = @dateone
```

(OR)

```
Update [dbo].[tabfget] set DATEIN = convert(varchar,GETDATE(),103 )
```

Yes, the format/style `103` should get you `/` instead of `-` like

```
select GETDATE()
```

will result in `2015-05-29 20:43:38.547`

```
select CONVERT(varchar(15), GETDATE(), 103)
```

Will result in `29/05/2015`

Comment: Thanks Rahul! Is thee any way to include slashes / instead of dashes - ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @dateone varchar(max)
declare @dodate varchar(max)

select @dateone=convert(varchar,GETDATE(),103 )

select @dodate='Update [dbo].[tabfget] set DATEIN='+quotename(@dateone,char(39));

Exec(@dodate);
```

Comment: The problem here is that you didn't address all the major implementation problems the OP posted. varchar(max) is absurd for a string representation of dates and there is absolutely zero need for dynamic sql here. This should be nothing more than a simple update statement.

Comment: Yes you could do it, without dynamic SQL Obviously, that's why I think maybe he wants that statement for something more complicated.

Comment: The quoting problem is actually something that others had not pointed out and was as major a mistake as any.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should do the update without dynamic sql. But the reason for the zero is that you're not quoting the date as a literal and it gets evaluated as integer division. (Format 103 is mm/dd/yyyy.)